# How can I update pgadmin3 to v1.14?

Tags: 11.10, postgresql

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday. From the repos I installed postgresql and pgadmin3. postgresql 9.1 is the current version but it seems pgadmin3 v1.12 is not properly compatible with 9.1.

How can I update it to use pgadmin3 v1.14?
I have tried to add this PPA https://launchpad.net/~rhonda/+archive/pgadmin3 but after I reload my sources I just get an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/postgres
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:voronov84/andreyv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Worked for me.

Comment: for postgres 9.2 compatibility, only the last one works, it installs version 1.16.0

Answer (score 2):

think i fixed it.
you've got to `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rhonda-pgadmin3-oneiric.list` and change **oneiric** to **natty**.

then run `sudo apt-get update` and if you open the package manager now you should see the new version of pgadmin3.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. PPA you are linking to provides beta-1 version only now. Could you please comment on stability/usability of this version?

Comment: @radek it is beta-1 but working fine for me :)

Comment: yup - working fine for me too :]

Comment: didn't work for me. i don't have rhonda-pgadmin3.oeriric.list