# upgrade pgadmin3 1.16 to 1.18

Tags: software-installation, postgresql, pg

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and have pgadmin3 1.16 installed.

I downloaded pgadmin3-1.18.1.tar.gz from http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.18.1/src/

I followed all the instructions found in the INSTALL file and make install seemed to work well.
the problem is that when I try to run pgadmin3, it still opens 1.16.

I tried uninstalling 1.16 and then reinstalling 1.18, but then I can't even find the executable.

my guess is that 1.18 is installed, how/where can I find it? or if not, how do I upgrade 1.16 to 1.18

thanks!

**EDIT**

the commands I ran are:

1. taken from [How can I update pgadmin3 to v1.14?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66099/how-can-i-update-pgadmin3-to-v1-14)
   and  http://linuxrails.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/install-pgadmin-for-postgresql-92-on.html

   - sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3
   - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:voronov84/andreyv
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
2. from pgadmin3-1.18.1/INSTALL

   - sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3
   - tar xvfz pgadmin3-1.18.1.tar.gz
   - cd pgadmin3-1.18.1
   - ./configure
   - make all
   - sudo make install

Comment: It would be great if you show us ever single command that you've entered. Check the bash history: `~/.bash_history`

Comment: none of the commands I ran show in this file :(

Comment: Oh, that means that you entered a lot of commands. Don't worry, is very common.

Comment: I added the 2 sets of commands I ran to the question above.

Comment: edit your question and include `type pgadmin3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Comment: first of all thanks! just thought to let you know that apt-get update throws: W: GPG error...: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8 after adding this line. had to fix it locally.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the key first using the following command. (The command downloads the key from the postgresql.org server and passes it to the apt-key command via a pipe)

```
 wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc|sudo apt-key add -
```

See http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/postgresql

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade Postgres SQL on Ubuntu the correct command is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade pgadmin3
```

Given that Postgres is already installed,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade pgadmin3
```

would return that pgadmin is already installed.